# How to filter a dataframe in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

If the given data frame is

```
A B C
1 0 0
3 0 1
4 0 8
5 0 0
```

How do we filter the above data frame such that only if all columns contain the value 0 except the first column.

```
A B C
3 0 1
4 0 8
```

Answer (score 2):

Try checking each column invididually and combining the Booleans using `greatest`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.filter(F.greatest(*[F.col(c) != 0 for c in df.columns[1:]]))

df2.show()
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  3|  0|  1|
|  4|  0|  8|
+---+---+---+
```